# Let $G$ be the group of rigid motions in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of a tetrahedron. Show that $|G|= 12$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

> Let $G$ be the group of rigid motions in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of a tetrahedron. Show that $|G| = 12$
>
> Hint: Find the number of positions to which an adjacent pair of vertices can be sent. Alternatively,  you can find the number of places to which a given face may be sent and, once a face is fixed, the number of positions to which a vertex on that face may be sent.

Now I have found out the answer using first hint. Let us label the vertices if tetrahedron $1,2,3,4$. Given any vertex $i$, there is a symmetry which  sends vertex $1$ into position $i$. Since vertex 2 is adjacent to vertex $1$, vertex 2 must
end up in position $i + 1 \ or\ i +2  \ or \ i+3$. Moreover, by following the first symmetry by a reflection about the line through vertex $i$, vertex
2 can be sent to either position $i + 1 \ or\ i +2  \ or \ i+3$  by some symmetry. Thus there are $n\times 3$ positions the ordered pair of vertices $1, 2$ may be sent to upon applying symmetries and as for tetrahedron $n=4$ we have $|G|=12$.

Now using the second alternative hint, I am facing some issues. According to the alternate hint we have to first find the number of places to which a given faces may be sent. Now there is $4$ faces of a tetrahedron.  [image: Tetrahedron] This $4$ faces  are according to this image $ABC,ACD,ABD,BCD$. Now consider the face $ABC$, it can be sent by rotation  to $ACD,ABD$, but is there any symmetry or refection such that it can be sent to face $BCD$? I can't find any. That's why using this hint, I have found no of places to which given a face may be sent is, for $ABC =ACD=ABD=2$, and for $BCD=0$. And no of positions to which a vertex on that face may be sent is $2$, as all face ar traingle. So no of rigid motions $=2×2+2×2+2×2+0×2=3×2×2=3×4=12$.

Is this reasoning okay? Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: You can send $ABC$ to any of the other sides by reflecting across the plane that bisects the dihedral angle between the two sides. For example, you can send $ABC$ to $DBC$ by reflecting across the plane going through $B$, $C$ and the middle of $AD$. Now if you want a different order of vertices, compose that reflection with a rotation of $120^\circ$ around an axis going through one vertex ad the middle of the opposite side.

Comment: Is the tetrahedron regular? If not, the group order is not $12$.

Comment: @paw88789 in dummit foote it's just how it is, there is no where mentioning of regular, but I think its regular.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I can't  understand this part "Now if you want a different order of vertices, compose that reflection with a rotation of $120^∘$ around an axis going through one vertex ad the middle of the opposite side. " can you elaborate?

Comment: @StinkingBishop so we have no. of places for which a given face may be sent = 3 faces through rotation + 1 through refection =4. And no of positions to which a vertex on that face sent $=3 (1,r,r^2)$. So we have $4×3=12$ rigid motions. Is this okay now?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, that is the gist of it. I also need to apologize - I was too quick to type my comment above. You cannot reflect across the plane because that is not a rigid motion in $\mathbb R^3$. However, you can substitute by rotation by $180^\circ$ around the axis connecting midpoints of two opposite edges. Say, if $X$ and $Y$ are the midpoints of $BC$ and $AD$, then rotation by $180^\circ$ around the axis $XY$ maps the side $ABC$ to $DCB$. To now map, say $DCB$ to $CBD$ or to $BDC$, rotate by $\pm 120^\circ$ around the axis connecting $A$ to the midpoint of the face $DCB$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop okay thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The group of rotations more or less obviously acts simply transitively on the set of half-edges, of which there are 12.

Answer (score 1):

There are 24 permutations of the vertices of a tetrahedron which form the group $S_4$, so there are 24 symmetries including reflections. Any reflection symmetry has a transformation matrix with determinant $-1$. If we look inside $S_4$, the group $G$ of all rotations has two cosets: $G$ and $aG$, where $a$ is a reflection. If there are more cosets, then they must have determinant $1$, which makes them a rotation, or $-1$. If $h$ is a rotation, then $ghg^{-1}$ is also a rotation if $g \in S_4$, because $ghg^{-1}$ has determinant $1$. Therefore, we can multiply $aG$ with the new coset and get another coset with determinant $1$, which doesn't exist. Therefore, there are only two cosets, which implies that $G$ has order $12$.