# Symmetries of Tetrahedron

Tags: group-theory, geometry, symmetry

I know there are 12 rotational symmetries of a regular tetrahedron ${T}$ (including the identity $e$), but I can only find 9 of them.

The first 8 are the $r = \pi/3$ rad rotations with 1 vertex fixed at a time. There are 4 vertices of interest, and there can only be 2 angles of rotation for each case ($r=\pi/3, r^2 = 2\pi/3$, with $r^3=e$), so then there are $2\cdot 4 = 8$ reflectional symmetries, plus the identity $e$, this gives $8+1=9$ symmetries. What are the other 3?

And I know there are 12 reflectional symmetries of $T$ as well.
I know I can reflect about the axes through the top vertex and the midpoints of bottom edge (there are 3 such axes). I can reflect about the axes that pass through a bottom vertex to the midpoint of the opposite face (3 more axes). Each reflection can only be done once, so this gives me 6 reflections. What could the other six be?

Comment: Here's another strategy: each rotational symmetry is determined by where it send your favorite distinguished vertex (4 choices) and then how it rotates about that vertex (3 choices). That gives you all 12. See if you can understand one of the ones that doesn't arise from your characterization.

Comment: Small correction. If you want $3$-fold symmetry when you rotate about an axis through a vertex and the center of the opposite face, then you want an angle of $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Comment: Choose two edges that don't share a vertex (there are 3 such pairs) and rotate the tetrahedron 180° around the axis that contains the centers of those edges.

Comment: You have found the symmetries that fix some vertex, the other three should be the ones that don't fix any of the vertices. Since we are *guessing* there are three such symmetries, if you take some $v$ and map it to one of the other three vertices, you *should* see that there is exactly one symmetry that doesn't fix any of the other three vertices.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493905/let-g-be-the-group-of-rigid-motions-in-mathbbr3-of-a-tetrahedron-show-t

Answer (score 3):

The regular tetrahedron has $6$ edges in $3$ opposite pairs. There is a $2$-fold symmetry (rotation through angle $\pi$) about the axis that pierces the midpoints of a pair of opposite edges. Look at the center image [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Tetrahedron#/Isometries_of_the_regular_tetrahedron).